# Unable to update Jenkins from 2.156 to 2.164

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to upgrade Jenkins from 2.156 to 2.164. Steps i performed

```
 Manage Jenkins -> Click on Upgrade button
```

it goes to /updateCenter and tries downloading but fails with the following exception

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
> Source)   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
> Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
> failed    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
> Source) Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException   at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
> at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown
> Source)   at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(Unknown Source)  at
> java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(Unknown
> Source)   at
> hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1165)
> Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown
> Source)   at
> hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1181)
> Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load
> https://updates.jenkins.io/download/war/2.264/jenkins.war to
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war.tmp    at
> hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1188)
> Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from
> https://updates.jenkins.io/download/war/2.264/jenkins.war     at
> hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1222)
> at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1759)
> at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1733)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
> hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I have tried

```
 Manage Jenkins ->Configure Global Security->Plugin Manager -> Checked Use Browser for metadata download



 Manage Jenkins-> Manage Plugins-> Advanced ->The Update Site is set to http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
```

Answer (score 0):

found it https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63515

I have upgraded java from `1.8.0.66` to `1.8.0_272`. I could not download JRE from oracle because oracle's new licensing restrictions but i have downloaded version 8 of OpenJDK from https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Then extracted the files -> Then Copied `jre` folder to JENKINS_HOME
On my machine JENKINS_HOME is  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`

You may have delete or  rename existing jre folder before coping.